# Check if a type is std::basic_string<T> at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have `is_string` defined as follow in my C++ code:

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct is_string
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class T, class Traits, class Alloc>
struct is_string<std::basic_string<T, Traits, Alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_string<std::string>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_string<std::wstring>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is true for both `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

But I need a predicate like this:

```
is_string<char, std::string>::value //to be true
is_string<char, std::wstring>::value //to be false
is_string<wchar_t, std::string>::value //to be false
is_string<wchar_t, std::wstring>::value //to be true
```

Is it possible to implement it?

Comment: Notice that you can inherit from `std::true_type`/`std::false_type` to shorten code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
struct is_string
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <class T, class Traits, class Alloc>
struct is_string<T, std::basic_string<T, Traits, Alloc>>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

In this specific case, a simpler solution would be:

```
template<class T, class S>
using is_string = std::is_same<T, typename S::value_type>;
```

(However, it doesn't check that the second type is actually a string, if that is fine with you - this solution checks if the second type is **any** container that holds elements of the first type)

Comment: The alternative with std::is_same is not a good idea, because it can be true for std::vector<char>, for example.

Comment: your first solution is the simple and elegant one. Your last solution spoils an otherwise good answer.  `is_string<int, std::vector<int>>` would be true

Comment: I used your first solution. I think it is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to make `is_string` taking two template parameters.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_string
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <class T, class Traits, class Alloc>
struct is_string<std::basic_string<T, Traits, Alloc>, void>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

Then

```
template <class T, template <typename, typename, typename> class STRING>
struct is_string<T, STRING<T, std::char_traits<T>, std::allocator<T>>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3oA6UsgBRNeVyrEN)

Comment: Of the three pieces of code, you only need the last one, right?

Comment: You need the first one to avoid compile errors when you were to get `false`, but the second is only needed if you want the base version with one argument. However, this will not accept strings with non-default traits or allocator.

Comment: @anatolyg I want to reserve the usage like `is_string<std::string>::value`.

Comment: @riv It depends on OP's intent; if necessary we can use parameter pack to make it applicable for non-default traits or allocator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
template<typename x_Char, typename x_String>
struct is_string
{
    static constexpr bool const value
    {
        (
            ::std::is_same_v<::std::string, x_String>
            or
            ::std::is_same_v<::std::wstring, x_String>
        )
        and
        ::std::is_same_v<typename x_String::value_type, x_Char>
    };
};

static_assert(true == is_string<char, std::string>::value); //to be true
static_assert(false == is_string<char, std::wstring>::value); //to be false
static_assert(false == is_string<wchar_t, std::string>::value); //to be false
static_assert(true == is_string<wchar_t, std::wstring>::value); //to be true
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rBk92HtK6Wwx88PF)

To deal with allocators:

```
template<typename x_Char, typename x_String>
struct is_string
: ::std::false_type {};

template<typename x_Char, typename x_CharTrait, typename x_Allocator>
struct is_string<x_Char, ::std::basic_string<x_Char, x_CharTrait, x_Allocator>>
: ::std::true_type {};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7esVYQFYMsAKtV87)

Comment: ::std::is_same_v<::std::string, x_String> - compares with a string that has the default allocator. What if the allocator is not default?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky From the question it looks like you don't care about allocators and only char type is relevant.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Updated my answer to include case that will deal with allocators as well.

Comment: I don't think you should specifically test with `std::string` and `std::wstring`. The type of string should be left to the user of the template. We now have many more `char` types (like `char32_t`) so you could have many different types of strings, not just these two.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++17 version.

```
namespace impl
{
    // decay_t will remove const, & and volatile from the type
    template<typename T>
    inline constexpr bool is_string_class_decayed = false;

    template<typename... T>
    inline constexpr bool is_string_class_decayed<std::basic_string<T...>> = true;
} // namespace impl

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_string_class = impl::is_string_class_decayed<std::decay_t<T>>;

template <typename TChar, typename TString>
inline constexpr bool is_string = is_string_class<TString> && std::is_same_v<TChar, TString::value_type>;


// Compile-time tests, you don't even need to write unit-tests to know it all works as expected
static_assert(is_string_class<std::string>);
static_assert(is_string_class<const std::wstring&>); // that's why we need decay_t
static_assert(!is_string_class<int>);
static_assert(!is_string_class<const double>);
static_assert(!is_string_class<const char*>);
static_assert(!is_string_class<std::vector<char>>);

static_assert(is_string<char, std::string>);
static_assert(is_string<wchar_t, std::wstring>);
static_assert(!is_string<char, std::wstring>);
static_assert(!is_string<wchar_t, std::string>);
```